# zooming into polyobj in zedgraph

Tags: c#, zooming, zedgraph

I'm using ZedGraph to write a Stepper Layout Program, where I have to be able to display items of dramatically different sizes next to one another.

Once I zoom into an area very deeply, filled polygon objects that are 200x larger than the current zoom rectangle simply disappear. How can I avoid this?

Code example:

```
GraphPane gp = zgc1.GraphPane;
gp.GraphObjList.Clear();

foreach (PointD[] pts in allpolygons)
{
    PolyObj po = new ZedGraph.PolyObj(pts, Color.Blue, Color.Red);
    gp.GraphObjList.Add(po);
}
```